# Identity Core Get Name & Other fields

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I have noticed that with Identity core I can get the name field in the following way:

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

I don't understand how this value is set and how would I add other fields to it such as MyCustomField or Address or Id. I've been looking over the open source https://github.com/aspnet/Identity however, I just can't seem to figure it out. Ideally, I would like to this outside of the identity project and within my own.

Can somebody explain to me how this works and how I would add more fields?

EDIT:

If I wanted to add Address I would write the following code:

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
     public static string GetAddress(this IIdentity identity)
     {
         return ((ClaimsIdentity) identity).FindFirst("Address").Value;
     }
 }
```

Now the above code allows me to pull the address value out of the claim, but what I don't understand is how to get the value saved in there.

If I were using EF then I would do that under `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method. However, I am not and I'm using dapper, so I'm trying to understand how this work. At what point would I read the information from the database and add it to the claim (I understand that would happen at login, but where in the code would this happen, how is the current Name being filled in)?

Comment: It's stored in the claims. See https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Core/ClaimsIdentityOptions.cs and https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Claims/src/System/Security/Claims/ClaimTypes.cs to see the claim definitions. Name property gets it form the claim set in user name, in this case `ClaimTypes.Name` and you can access it via `User.Identity.Claims`

Answer (score 3):

I accomplished this by doing the following:

1 - Added a new column to [AspNetUsers] table named [staff_id] in the database.

2 - Created an ApplicationUser class that inherits from IdentityUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
 public ApplicationUser(){ }
 public int staff_id { get; set; }
}
```

3 - Created a class AppClaimsPrincipalFactory  that inherits UserClaimsPrincipalFactory and overrides the CreateAsync method.

```
public class AppClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
{
    public AppClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                                     RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
                                     IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor
                                    ): base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor){  }
    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);

        ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] {
            new Claim("staff_id",user.staff_id.ToString())
        });

        return principal;
    }
}
```

4 - Modified Startup.cs ConfigureServices method, adding code to use my local AppClaimsPrincipalFactory class to customize the User upon login

```
//add Entity Framework 
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));

//add Identity framework, specify which DbContext to use
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

//add local AppClaimsPrincipalFactory class to customize user
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

5 - Finally I access the claim as follows, there may be a better way but this is how I access the staff_id of the authenticated user.

```
int iStaffId;
if(!Int32.TryParse(User.FindFirst("staff_id").Value, out iStaffId))
{
 //throw an error because the staff_id claim should be present in iStaffId
}
```

Some other resources I found useful are below. Good luck.

[How to extend ASP.NET Core Identity user](https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/identity/extend-user-model.html)

[ASP.NET Core Identity 3.0 : Modifying the Identity Database](https://medium.com/@goodealsnow/asp-net-core-identity-3-0-6018fc151b4)

[Configure the ASP.NET Core Identity primary key data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough post. What I am a little confused about is that you create a claim on `CreateAsync` method. Which means these claims are created when the user is first created. So your claim is then taken and written to the database claims table? What happens when the value changes, how do you update that?

Comment: I have an edit form to add/edit new users [AspNetUsers]. My form has a drop down list for the staff_id column that is in the table. Now when that user I created attempts to login the Identity framework verifies the user name and password corresponds to the record in the table. If the user logs in successfully, the custom claim staff_id is loaded/stored on the authenticated User. Does that help? To answer your question: The claim is created every time that user logs into the app, no claims is stored in another table. You change the value of the claim by updating the record in the database.